# Is there a link between frequent Virtual Server crashes and time synchronization

Tags: windows-server-2012, virtual-machines, time-synchronization

I am running a 4GB Virtual Server (VMWare) running Tomcat on Windows Server 2012 R2. The server is subject to unexplained restarts every two weeks or so.

While searching the event log I filtered on events 6008 and 1, and note that while the time is synced every day, the crashes seem to happen always about five minutes after a time synchronization.

For example: (Note that the server time is 2 hours ahead of GMT)

```
"Error  04/07/2017 09:14    EventLog    6008    None    The previous system shutdown at 11:29:20 PM on ‎7/‎3/‎2017 was unexpected."

"Information    04/07/2017 00:23    Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General    1   None    ""The system time has changed to ‎2017‎-‎07‎-‎03T21:23:28.146000000Z from ‎2017‎-‎07‎-‎03T21:23:24.763014700Z."
```

Now obviously, correlation does not prove causation, but it does seem very interesting. Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. A time sync would not cause a system crash like you have.

Time offset can cause other errors, like kerberos error, authentication error, etc.. but not a system crash.

I would inspect other windows log and check to have the option to create a crashdump, to be able to find why the system crashed.

Comment: Thank you! But is it possible for a time offset of a few seconds to cause the VMWare to clash with the Hypervisor and for that to crash the system

Comment: @gordon613 Vmware tool itselft do time sync with the host too, but I did run some VM with time of like 8 years offset and it did nothing. It just break like windows update, that dont want to complete with a bad date.